# Can the root ש ל ם be used to mean “Submission”?

Tags: words, hebrew

In Arabic, the root S-L-M (س ل م) has a general meaning of "Peace", but can also be used for "Submission" (such as in the words Islam/Muslim).  Given the close relation between Hebrew and Arabic, I'm curious to know whether the Hebrew Sh-L-M (ש ל ם) can be similarly interpreted thus.

In particular, was this root ever used to refer to those who *whole-heartedly submitted* themselves to the Mosaic Law (and thus to G-D's authority)?  If not, was a different term (with similar meaning) used for these people, in order to distinguish them from the children of Israel as a whole?

I got following Hebrew terms from a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0-L-M):

- **Mushlam** (מושלם) — perfect
- **Shalem** (שלם) — whole, complete

Have these concepts ever been extended to **perfect** (*Mushalam*) followers or **complete** (*Shalem*) submission in the *Tanach*?

P.S: This question evolved [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26263/can-the-root-be-used-to-mean-submission)

Answer (score 4):

> In particular, was this root ever used to refer to those who whole-heartedly submitted themselves to the Mosaic Law (and thus to G-D's authority)?

A word with that root was never used for that purpose that I know of, but I'm no expert in all of Hebrew-language Jewish writings from all time. Nor, even, in *Tanach*.

> If not, was a different term (with similar meaning) used for these people, in order to distinguish them from the children of Israel as a whole?

Yes.

In Exodus 32:26, Moses says "מִי לַה׳ אֵלָי", roughly "whoever is God's, come to me". He was referring to those who were wholeheartedly following God, to distinguish them from the children of Israel as a whole, just as you seek. (See the context in Exodus there.) So the term you seek is "מִי לַה׳", roughly "whoever is God's". But note that that phrase is not generally read as a substantive.

Probably closer to what you're seeking is Deuteronomy 18:13. There, we have "תָּמִים תִּהְיֶה עִם ה׳ אֱלֹקֶיךָ". This is a difficult phrase to translate, and a difficult one to interpret. Interpretation first: Rashi and especially Nachmanides say it means that we should look only to God and that if astrologers or the like tell us what will happen we should nonetheless trust that God can do whatever he wishes. The key word here is "תָּמִים", which the JPS here translates as "whole-hearted" but which really means "complete": Onkelus here translates it into Aramaic as "שַׁלְמִין", from the root you seek. Rabbi Kaplan (*The Living Torah*) translates it as "totally faithful".

Comment: can you pronounce the hebrew words you quoted

Comment: @Ali, well, it includes the tetragrammaton, so the real pronunciation is unknown to us (or me). The usual pronunciation is /mi ladonɑj elɑj/, but that uses God's name. The usual pronunciation religious Jews would use to avoid saying God's name unnecessarily is /mi laʃɛm elɑj/. (Pronunciation varies by dialect, though.)

Comment: @Ali, you can hear it in context by downloading Exodus 32 from [here](http://www.aoal.org/hebrew_audiobible.htm#Exodus) and skipping to 04:49 of the MP3. Note that as far as I know, this is the only use of this term in the Bible. I believe it was used once again in the post-Biblical Chanuka story.

Comment: For the second term ("tamim tiheh"), get Deuteronomy 18 from [here](http://www.aoal.org/hebrew_audiobible.htm#Deuteronomy), and skip to around 01:53.

Comment: I object to this answer because it can give the incorrect impression that מִי לַה׳ is a standard appellation for a subgroup of devoted followers (which someone might write out as Milashem, which probably looks a lot like Mushalem or Muslim to the OP who seems intent on establishing a connection). Of course, as you and @IsaacMoses pointed out in the comments, this is not how the term would actually have been spoken. Also, there's no reason to think that this was ever meant as a title to categorize or characterize a group of Jews (the only title these people had was *Levi*)...

Comment: ... So offering this in the answer seems like feeding into the OP's fantasy.

Comment: @Fred, I refuse to accept responsibility for someone's (potential) misunderstanding of my post if such misunderstanding would necessarily be born of ignoring most of that post and focusing on only the part that, out of context, looks like it supports his preconceived notion. That said, see my recent edit: better now?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, it's an improvement (especially for readers who know what a substantive is). Still, the whole paragraph does not sit well with me. More suitable examples might be "v'avdi Chaleiv" (B'midbar 14:24), "avdi Moshe" (ibid. 12:7, M'lachim II 21:8), "el avdi el David" (Sh'muel II 7:5), "avadai hanvi'im" (M'lachim II 9:7; ibid. 17:13), "avdi Y'sha'yahu" (Y'sha'yahu 20:3), etc., etc. (Of course, you are under no obligation to satisfy me with your answer, nor am I obligated to be satisfied).

Comment: @Fred, re "_avdi_": there's also "_ki avaday hem_" (in _parashas B'har_ IIRC). Why not post an answer yourself?

Comment: @msh210 (1.) Yes, that's a good example. (2.) Maybe I'll post if someone comes along with a different question. I'd rather let this one be.

Comment: @Fred re your last comment, someone has come along with [a different question](/q/68342).

Answer (score 3):

Just by way of reference, and by no means is this the authority on the subject, Google Translate [shows several Hebrew words for "submission"](http://translate.google.com/#en/iw/submission), none of which has the root Sh-L-M.

The closest I can think of to your desired translation are:
שולם/Shulam = paid (passive voice)
נשלם/Nishlam = completed; also paid (passive voice)

The reason I say these examples are close is that they convey a sense of someone having fulfilled an obligation (although fulfilled is usually translated in the root M-L-A [where A is an Aleph], P-T-R, or Y-Tz-A, depending on the context).